# Не могу создать проект С++

Tags: unreal-engine

> An error occurred while trying to generate project files.
>
> Running E:/Epic
> games/UE_5.0/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe
> -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/grish/OneDrive/Документы/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress A fatal
> error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.
> If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in
> [E:\Epic games\UE_5.0\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool]. If
> this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the
> global location [C:\Program Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT
> environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the
> runtime location in
> [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].
>
> The .NET Core runtime can be found at:
>
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

Вот такая ошибка вылетает

Comment: На blueprint всё прекрасно создаёться

Comment: И? Установили .NET Core runtime?

Comment: @void, .NET установлен

Comment: Именно тот самый, о котором в тексте ошибки говорится?

Comment: В этой ошибке я не увидел конкретики, но в предыдущей было 3.1, который и стоит

Comment: А что в C:\Program Files\dotnet? Пробовали принудительно системную переменную добавить DOTNET_ROOT? Что в [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation]? Пробовали переустановить .NET Core 3.1, что по ссылке?

Comment: Пробовала переустановить

Comment: Извините, но я не понимаю что должно быть в C:\Program Files\dotnet (максимум представляю что там должен быть .NET, но я не знаю как он должен выглядеть, но я могу добавить правку со скринами), я вообще не понимаю что за системные переменные такие,